# How to easily give customers graphical access to SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Our website runs for many customers as a software as a service.

They have asked to be able to import their data in our database. Since the database has many customers, each one will have different needs of what fields map to what and what needs to be transformed.

We could write our own mapping tool and do a BULK Insert, which is ok.

I have never used SSIS but have read that this is the kind of thing it does. If so, how do we give them access to SSIS? Is it like report builder where you can download a "user interface" and the customer can do it (simply...they are not computer literate past Excel), or do we have to program the package (in which case may as well do it ourselves)?

Their data is likely to be CSV or Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSIS is not a customer tool. It is complex and takes a strong understanding of ETL processes. There is a 0% chance that typical customer users would be able to create an import using it.

We have hundreds of imports using SSIS and a staff of close to 10 to create and monitor them.  All very senior professionals.  This is not simple stuff if you do it correctly.

Our development model is that we create a standard package to do the work most typically needed by a customer. If they want to use the standard, we then require they send us a file in a standard format so that we can hook the import up. We do this using parent and child packages sowe can change the configurations for each customer. We do not allow people to send Excel files if using the standard processes. At a minimum get CSVs, as Excel and SSIS a do not play well together. Pipe-delimited text files are best though. This is the least expensive option as it takes far less time to hook up a new parent package wilh a standard file than to create a custom package.

Other clients require custom imports. We do those too, but charge much more money for them as they will take more than twice as much time. Custom imports and exports we are doing for a new client right now  have well over 2000 hours in the estimate (this is for multiple imports and exports). It is not unusual to spend over a 100 hours of development time on one import. This is not a quick or cheap task. If they are giving you an Excel file estimate the cost at twice the cost of a CSV or text file. Excel really is that bad to import. Once they understand that it is more expensive to do, most places will not provide an Excel file.

Do not just create just a bulk insert to a production table. This is the way to have data integrity problems. (Data from Excel and csv is notoriously bad, much worse than data that came from a database generally.) Data from files needs to be staged and evaluated for data issues and cleaned if possible. Our packages send bad data to an exception table, so the client can know what needs to be fixed (we email the exceptions to the client). We also do some fairly standard cleaning on things like phone numbers to make sure they are fomatted correctly. Some types of errors cause the entire import to fail. You would need to determine the requirements for what is a good file and what errors are a problem. These can vary greatly depending on the type of data.

Customers need to be educated on what they can and cannot do in sending files. The first rule is that any file structure change is a **programming** change and the client will be charged to make the change and the change must be approved in advance and given time like any other programming task. There are no last minute file changes to the file struture. Those will cause an automatic faillure of the import. Once they realize that such changes are costly and will result in their data not being immediately available, most clients will try to keep such changes to a minimum necessary.

Always charge for doing import work and for the support time it takes to track down import errors and determine the cause. In general, once a import is stable and on prod, it is rare that the problem is a bug in the code, it is almost always a problem of bad data in the file. However, the client will need to know exactly what data is bad and why.  Incidentally, in setting up a process, never throw the orginal file away after the import, alawys keep it in an archive. You will eventually need to research some incorrect data that may have been imported months or years earlier and you will need those files to prove that your process was not wrong, their data was.

Imports are code like any other project. They should be in source control and they should have the same level of QA testing that other code has. They should be code reviewed.

When you have a system with lots of data imports, you need to understand that the data is critical to the success or failure of the product. Clients leave because of bad data problems more than because of an awkward or difficult to use user interface. You should have specialists to deal with data if it is the lifeblood of your business.  More money and devlopement time should be spent on data than the application in every application that deals with data extensively and especially if it deals in any way with privacy issues, legal or regulartory issues, and/or money. Data is what will make or break an application that is not trivial in scope.

Comment: +1 Every part of this answer is right on the money and is excellent advice for anyone doing data imports